# this.prop trampling in textarea change handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to learn React. In my sample app, other components need to know if a document (content of a textarea) is unsaved.

One method I'm trying is having my parent component inject a prop which can be called by the child "editor" component.

Except, when `handleChange` is called from the textarea, `this.props` no longer refers to the Editor. I'm sure I have `this` trampling but am not sure on the recommended way to resolve it.

```
export default class Editor extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log(this.props);
        // this.props.setUnsaved(true);
    }

    render() {
        return <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} />;
    }
};
```

If there are better ways to share the "unsaved" state, I'm open to them. Eventually I'll need a better model system, and might use Backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the ES6 class version of React classes (as opposed to using `React.createClass`), functions aren't auto-bound (see [No Autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) from the React docs). So, you need to manually bind the function, perhaps with:

```
render() {
    return <textarea onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />;
}
```

If you don't want to have to bind the function every time you use it, you can also manually bind the functions when you initialize the class:

```
constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

or, if you're using a transpiler that supports [ES7 property initializers](https://gist.github.com/jeffmo/054df782c05639da2adb) (like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), with the [`es7.classProperties`](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/03/31/5.0.0/#stage-0:-class-properties) configuration option set), you can define functions you want to be bound using arrow function properties:

```
class Editor extends React.Component {
    ...
    handleChange = (event) => {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured I was missing something like this, thanks.